# Adding controls dynamically in User control throwing duplicate ID error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a couple of text boxes in a user control that I am using in a web form. When the Add button on the user control is clicked, the corresponding section is hidden in the user control. 
The Issue now is, the Text boxes are only added a couple of times on clicking the Add button. The subsequent clicks return duplicate ID error. Not sure on how to resolve this. Here is the Webform, User control and .ascx.cs files.

Error:

```
Multiple controls with the same ID '534011718' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.
    at Function.Error$create [as create] (ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O8UhT6CQuRknbIyh_6ghEShYes4N6ARI-DqYYcqzd-pVr-FbAymdbS_TdRP62S_zr…:237)
```

Webform:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleWebApp.WebForm1" %>



<%@ Register Src="~/DataInputUC.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="DataInputUC" %>


    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <div>
                Please Enter User Input:
                <uc1:DataInputUC runat="server" id="DataInputUC" />
            </div>
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

UserControl.ascx

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DataInputUC.ascx.cs" Inherits="SampleWebApp.DataInputUC" %>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="numOfTB" runat="server" Value="0" />
        <asp:Table ID="UserCOntrolTable" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_field1" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_PhoneNo" runat="server" Text="Phone No:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_phoneNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Add" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btn_Add_Click" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Usercontrol.ascx.cs:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SampleWebApp
{
    public partial class DataInputUC : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateControls();
        }

        protected void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
            tRow.Cells.Add(cell1);
            tRow.Cells.Add(cell2);
            tRow.Cells.Add(cell3);
            this.UserCOntrolTable.Rows.Add(tRow);
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = "Name";
            Label lbl2 = new Label();
            lbl2.Text = "Phone No:";
            cell1.Controls.Add(lbl);
            cell2.Controls.Add(lbl2);

            TextBox name = new TextBox();
            Random x = new Random(1);
            name.ID = x.Next().ToString();
            cell1.Controls.Add(name);
            TextBox Phnno = new TextBox();
            Phnno.ID = x.Next().ToString();
            cell2.Controls.Add(Phnno);
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "Delete";
            cell3.Controls.Add(btn);

            Panel pan = new Panel();
            pan.Controls.Add(tRow);
            UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(pan);
            this.numOfTB.Value = (Convert.ToInt16(this.numOfTB.Value) + 2).ToString();
        }

       void PopulateControls()
        {
            int tbs = Convert.ToInt16(this.numOfTB.Value);
            for(int i=0;i<tbs/2;i++)
            {
                TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
                TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
                tRow.Cells.Add(cell1);
                tRow.Cells.Add(cell2);
                tRow.Cells.Add(cell3);
                this.UserCOntrolTable.Rows.Add(tRow);
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = "Name";
                Label lbl2 = new Label();
                lbl2.Text = "Phone No:";
                cell1.Controls.Add(lbl);
                cell2.Controls.Add(lbl2);

                TextBox name = new TextBox();
                Random x = new Random(1);
                name.ID = x.Next().ToString();
                cell1.Controls.Add(name);
                TextBox Phnno = new TextBox();
                Phnno.ID = x.Next().ToString();
                cell2.Controls.Add(Phnno);
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Text = "Delete";
                cell3.Controls.Add(btn);

                Panel pan = new Panel();
                pan.Controls.Add(tRow);
                UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(pan);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to append a name of the textbox to your id.

for example

```
name.ID = "name_" + x.Next().ToString();
Phnno.ID = "Phnno_" + x.Next().ToString();
```

See if the issue remains.

Comment: I believe the error is due to Rand generator is generating the same id when called multiple times. If that's the case, appending the same text wouldn't work as well but I'll give a try